# Is it possible to take column names for sqlite database as input from user in an android app?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am creating an android app for my college faculties through which they will be able to keep and maintain the attendance of students in their lectures.
I thought of designing the database this way

Date | Student1 | Student2 | . . . . . . |. . .|. . . | Student60

In this structure each INSERT INTO statement will take 61 values, one for the date and rest for presence/absence record of 60 students.
But in this case the column headers have to be named by the user(the column header should be unique identifier for that particular student, like his roll no.). Is it possible? or am I completely on the wrong track?
Please suggest if there is a better database design alternative.
I also need to provide the users the ability to retrieve aggregate attendance % of a student.
Apologies in advance if I've asked something very basic or stupid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is on the wrong track.  Instead, make the student's ID a primary key column, and use the other columns for storing student metadata, something like this:

Students

```
ID | first_name | last_name |
1  | Jon        | Skeet     |
2  | Gordon     | Linoff    |
...
```

Attendance

```
ID | SID | date       | status
1  | 1   | 2017-05-24 | absent
2  | 1   | 2017-05-25 | present
3  | 2   | 2017-05-24 | present
4  | 2   | 2017-05-25 | present
```

Now if you wanted to find out which students were present on a given day you could use the following query:

```
SELECT
    s.first_name,
    s.last_name
FROM Students s
INNER JOIN Attendance a
    ON s.ID = s.SID
WHERE a.status = 'present' AND
      a.date = '2017-05-24'
```

Note that in practice you might use an integer (0 or 1) to store the attendance.

Towards answering your actual question, if you wanted a summary by student along with his attendance record in percent over the most recent 90 days, you could use this:

```
SELECT SID, 100*(SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'present' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / 90) AS p_attedance
FROM Attendance
WHERE date > date('now', '-90 days');
GROUP BY SID
```

Comment: Thanks for your time.. i was wondering that in this way, say, the record is to be maintained for 90 days. Then the number of rows in the attendance  table will be 90*60=5400. Am i correct?   Also, if this is the case can u please provide a query to retrieve the aggregate(total classes attended/total classes held) over a period of, say 90 days for a particular student?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, and it means that for 60 students you would have roughly 20K records in a given calendar year.  This is not as big a number as you might think.  Even millions of records should be manageable assuming that you have indices setup properly.  Once students graduate, you could archive their old records.

Comment: Off the top of my head, one trick you might want to use here would be to only record an absence event.  That is, when students show up as expected, you don't add to the table, you would only record a student not showing up, which presumably is a fairly rare event.  This way, you could cut down on the amount of data you need to store, perhaps by 90% or more.

Comment: thanks again... one last doubt although regarding the query to get the aggregate for a student(also asked in previous comment).

Comment: Your question is unclear, because my table design doesn't match what you expect.  You should at least update your question and show your expected output.

Comment: It sounds like you want class level attendance data.  In this case, we can add a `class` column to the `Attendance` table.  As for your query, show me the output you want and maybe I can help you.

Comment: The output wanted here is the percentage of lectures attended by a particular student. e.g. say for 90 days, everyday a particular lecture is held and one student has only attended 45 of them. Then the user of the app(faculty in this case) should be able to get this percentage((45/90)*100=50%) through a sql query, and i'm not sure how that query can be structured.